# How do you get an object to spawn in a specific weapon but with the attachments and skins

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interaction, preference

I am a VR developer but never had to code thanks to the tools readily available but now i have decided to make my own game and learn C# i have looked here and there but cannot find a definitive answer. To be more specific player is in hub and makes adjustments to a weapon that is in my game. Player doesnt start with this weapon, should player interact with an object that can spawn this weapon how do you make it spawn in to them with all the attachments and skins they added back in the hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the Game Object with the weapon in DontDestroyOnLoad after the player is done and move it back to scene and use it. (I suppose you change the scene from hub to game, after customizing the weapon)

Use it on a script, that have the weapon as reference:

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(weapon);
```

Then, use this in the other scene, to get it back and put it in your character's hand (you need a reference):

```
SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(weapon, SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
weapon.transform.parent = characterHand.transform;
```

Comment: Yuris you are a legend thanks alot for your input. So ellaborating abit more lets say there is a interactable that spawns a weapon which 4 coop players can access how do you program it to give each individual player the preferences they set back in the hub?

Comment: Sorry i dont mean to be persistent or expect other people to build my game for me. the help you have already given me is golden just really dont have a clue on this aspect.

Comment: No problem. You can save the preferences in PlayerPrefs, and regenerate them when is needed. You have to make a script that remembers the id's of his settings and regenerate it. Take a look: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: Yuri you are a legend!! Thanks soo much If you have or get a Quest 2 give me a shout and ill sort you out when the game releases

Comment: I don't have one, but I appreciate it. Take care and good luck. ;)